# Avoid emails to send in Junk/Spam

Tags: codeigniter, email

I my CI application I want to send email in inbox.

I checked my server IP on http://www.mxtoolbox.com/Public/Tools/Blacklists.aspx & it is not in any blacklist but if i send email to hatmail it goes to **junk** is there any way to by pass email to inbox?

I have tested both CI email lib as well as PHP mail function but both send email in junk/spam also just send with a text **Hello** from my gmail id.

Comment: Do you have access to the mails on the hatmail server? You could look at the mail header (post it here?). A reason for the junk classification should be mentioned there.

Comment: Chances are it has more to do with the email content and subject line than it does any blacklist. Crafting a business email that doesn't end up in a junk folder is an art.

Comment: You can for starters try sending it with html headers.  That usually bumps it up a bit but is not guarantee of not ending up in the spam folder.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [php - sending emails with codeigniter received in junk mail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11843123/sending-emails-with-codeigniter-received-in-junk-mail)