# CodeIgniter email to spam and from id with gmail not delivering properly

Tags: codeigniter, email, spam

I am working with `CodeIgniter` and trying to send `email` using `CodeIgniter's default email library`. I am facing two major issues

**1. Mail are going to spam folder**

**2. Mail ID with domain name as `gmail.com` is prevent from delivering**

For the first question, I referenced threads [Question 1](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB0QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F22433418%2Fwhy-by-codeigniter-email-is-going-to-spam-folder-with-full-information&ei=7n8vVamFJcPhuQTFtID4Aw&usg=AFQjCNFzS3Q61Ar0wmMpH5sv7pRwy7Wn8w&sig2=pZZiKvaVwwJmHxOYRo9L_w&bvm=bv.91071109,d.c2E),[Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12714969/codeigniter-mail-to-going-to-spam-any-solution),[Question 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11843123/sending-emails-with-codeigniter-received-in-junk-mail)

But none of the above helped me.

**Can I use any custom header for this purpose?**

If there is a proper solution other tha the above, Please help me..

And for the second question, is it a server related issue? because it delivering mails from `someonee@hotmail.com` but not from `someone@gmail.com`.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It isn't that "going to spam" mails are only because of code. Get in touch with your server administrator and ask him to check if ur IP is blacklisted and get it whitelisted, if that is the case

Answer (score 0):

Email going into spam or not in inbox is not related to your code.

There are multiple reasons by which emails can go into spam folder

- You using email which is marked as spam.
- Your IP address is blacklisted
- The Keywords you using is spammy.

Try to send the email with third party api (Mailchimp or mailgun) and good keywords.